# Canceled timer and screen lock

Tags: android

I have created an app which use count down timer, the problem is that the timer stops completely when the screen gets locked. 
I already know that this happens due to onStop() is invoked,
So my question is how to prevent stopping the timers' work without needing to cancel screen lock?

Comment: Can we know more about what the use of the countdown timer is for? There can be multiple ways to solve this the best solution will depend on your use case

Comment: I am using four timers to calculate the running time of my customers who plays PS4 games. So, I have 4 ps4 and I want to calculate the running time of all of them or 2 or 3 depending on the customers' number.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would store the start time, persist it or save with onSaveInstanceState and then recalculate / start your timers again when your activity has resumed. I feel this would be the easier and more reliable solution

Comment: Thanks alot, but the question is if I recalculate /start or timer, I will no longer know the real customer's time spent and he will spend more time than the supposed one.